# Ethereum block header: What is the purpose of the recipientsRoot?

Tags: ethereum

I'm looking into how the Ethereum block header works, but just on a basic level, as I'm not a programmer. What is the purpose of the recipientsRoot in the Ethereum block header? Wouldn't the recipients already be recorded in the transactionRoot?